# Need comparison of MVVM / WPF / Silverlight Toolkits

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm-light, caliburn

I'm looking for a good article that compares MVVM Light, Caliburn Micro, Prism, and any other Silverlight / WPF / WP7 frameworks out there. I've seen some good articles on them individually, but nothing that really pits them against one another. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this article http://www.japf.fr/2009/10/a-quick-tour-of-existing-mvvm-frameworks/

My recomandation if the app is not too big, better use MVVM Light, and after that deppending of your requirements, Prism(Last Version), nRoute, or Caliburn .

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty stoked about Caliburn Micro after watching the author's talk at Mix http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX15, but I'll give MVVM Light a try before committing.

Comment: Bear in mind as well that Prism addresses a different set of needs in general. Also, the article referenced talks about the "old" version of Caliburn, not Caliburn Micro.